# libgit2 how to resolve short ref name to full ref name or hash

Tags: git, libgit2

In libgit2, how to resolve short ref name to get the full ref name or hash?
What libgit2 function need to be called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

libgit2 supports the full **[extended SHA-1 syntax](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)** through the use of the `git_revparse_single()` function. In order to retrieve the hash, just pass the retrieved object to the `git_object_id()`function.

Leveraging `git_revparse_single()` will allow one to replicate following standard git command line usages:

```
$ git show master
$ git show heads/master
$ git show e90810b
...
```

**Libgit2 code:**

```
git_repository* repo;
git_object *object;
int error;

... open existing repository ...

/* Short named references
 * Note: Might be considered ambiguous if tags/master
 * and heads/master both exist
 */
error = git_revparse_single(&obj, repo, "master"); 
git_object_free(obj);

/* Less ambiguous name */
error = git_revparse_single(&obj, repo, "heads/master");
git_object_free(obj);

/* Short hash as well */
error = git_revparse_single(&obj, repo, "e90810b"); 
git_object_free(obj);

/* Complex specs */
error = git_revparse_single(&obj, repo, "master@{0}~1^1"); 
git_object_free(obj);

/* Tree entries */
error = git_revparse_single(&obj, repo, "test/master@{1}:branch_file.txt"); 
git_object_free(obj);
```

For more information or examples about usage, you can peek at the **[unit tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/refs/revparse.c)**.

**Note:** There's currently no built-in exposed way to retrieve a canonical reference name from a short reference name.

### Update

The amazing **[@CarlosMartinNieto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370215/carlos-martin-nieto)** made it happen.

Libgit2 now exposes `git_reference_dwim` which retrieves a reference by its short name (e.g. `master`, `heads/master`, ...)

- **[Header](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/refs.h#L57-L68)**
- **[Libgit 2 commit introducing this change](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/98d633cccf0a214b83ebfe9c7cb8ca449a1f0637)**